# Read txt files from build without writing them

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, io, text-files

I want to make a console application which tests a .txt file to be included with the application. However, File.ReadAllLines(string) seems to have only the string-filepath constructor and not one taking the file itself, which could be accessed by 
mytextfile = myProject.Properties.Resources.mytextfile.txt;

so do I have to write the file from the build somewhere, call reflection on it to find out its full path and only then be able to use ReadAllLines() to convert it into a string-array? is there no easier way to do this?

Comment: If you have the file as an *embedded resource*, you don't need ReadAllLines(string) which *reads from disk*. I'm not sure what this question is about or how writing is involved.. but I suspect the real question is: "How to read all embedded text file lines as a string array?"

Comment: What if I want to allow the user to call the testing method either on the file in the build or one he could choose himself?

And what would be the alternative to ReadAllLines(string) to read it from the build?

Comment: Then use different code to access the resource in different ways. The code can unify around a *Stream* - once such is opened then it can be read in the same way. Then it's just a matter of "Reading a Text Stream line-by-line" or "reading a Text Stream into a string array", and it doesn't matter if the Stream is from the Disk or an Embedded Resource.

Comment: Ref. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292 , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the embedded resource as a stream like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.mytextfile.txt");
```

and then get the text from the stream like this:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Am I missing something or does StreamReader have no method to return an array of strings from the lines in the file it has read? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx How do I find out the number of lines to create an equally big array and use a loop to fill it?

Comment: Use ReadLine instead in a loop: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx: